# Friends android devices cannot install my android app, I cant even do it for my own

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest

I recently uploaded my android app to the marketplace https://market.android.com/details?id=com.DGNT yet my friends cannot install it on their devices (says their phone is incompatible).  The site even says my own phone is incompatible for my own app, even though i have compiled it through eclipse and sucessfully installed the apk on my phone and tablet. (telus LGE LG-p500h and asus transformer tf101)

Is there something wrong with my app or should i just wait a little longer to see what happens?  Ive been told my manifest could have something to do with it so here is what i got.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.DGNT"
      android:versionCode="2"
      android:versionName="1.01">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name="com.DGNT.MainScreenActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         <activity android:name="com.DGNT.QuickStartActivity"
                  android:label="Quick Start"
                  android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        </activity>
         <activity android:name="com.DGNT.ManagePlayersActivity"
             android:label="Manage Players">

         </activity>
               <activity android:name="com.DGNT.PlayerListActivity"
             android:label="Start From Player List"
             android:screenOrientation="portrait">

         </activity>
               <activity android:name="com.DGNT.EditPlayersActivity" 
              android:label="Edit Players">

               </activity>

              <activity android:name="com.DGNT.CreditsActivity" 
              android:label="Credits">

               </activity>
 <activity android:name="com.DGNT.HelpActivity" 
              android:label="Help">

               </activity>
                <activity android:name=".AboutActivity" 
              android:label="About">

               </activity>


<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>




    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely have a `<supports-screens />` element in your manifest to list the screen sizes your app is compatible with. Try adding this just after your opening `manifest` tag:

```
<supports-screens
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true" />
```

That should open up the app for any type of screen. Obviously I'm assuming here that you want it available for any screen size, so tweak as needed! More details [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html).

Hope that solves it for you

Comment: Thanks for your response.  i added that tag in my app and uploaded the new version but my friends and i still cant install (or have the option to install) it.  What i dont get is why do i need to change anything, it clearly works on my phone so why cant i install it?  my dad has the same phone as me and he cant install it either.  strange

Comment: Ah that's a shame - thought that would solve it. Will update if I think of anything else that could be the cause